# Create a delay for jquery mobile loader widget

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, delay, loader

I'm working on a jquery.mobile application for a shop system.

Basically my idea is the following:
To improve usability and user experience I have a full screen loader widget with a spinning pizza that is displayed whenever jquery mobile loads a page via AJAX. That works fine so far with the native options provided.

Now i try to explain my problem:
Of course it's great to show the user that the application is loading. But when connected to a wireless LAN at home for example the loading times are minimal. Still the loader always shows up for a second making the application feel even less like a real native app.

Now i read about the caching system and also tried it out and it works fine. As far as i understood the caching of pages disables the loader by adding a delay.

heres the code from my jquery.mobile.custom.js (about line 5358)

```
    _showLoading: function( delay, theme, msg, textonly ) {
        // This configurable timeout allows cached pages a brief
        // delay to load without showing a message
        if ( this._loadMsg ) {
            return;
        }

        this._loadMsg = setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            this._getLoader().loader( "show", theme, msg, textonly );
            this._loadMsg = 0;
        }, this), delay );
    },
```

So that's exactly what i need.
I want to show the loading widget only after about 200 - 500 ms so the user doesn't always call the loading widget although the page is close to instantly there.

Does anyone already have experience with a solution? Would this be a usefull addition or suggestion for the devs?

Sadly there are no special events mentioned you could call whenever a loader starts.

I'd be happy if you shared your ideas with me. :)

Comment: The best way, is to modify jQM JS itself. Because `_showLoading` is a private function and can't extended outside the scope of jQM JS.

Comment: Could you delay the showing of the spinning pizza by 200-500ms with a setTimeout, and then when the new page loads, clear the timeout? That way only longer AJAX calls will show the spinning pizza.

Comment: That's exactly what i planned to do. But since the loader widget itself can't be modified I couldn't affect the event. I added a possible solution with an effect close to what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The following Solution doesn't properly work on every device... So it's pretty limited. I'm looking for a better solution at the moment. I'll let you know!

---

Modifying frameworks is just trouble if you want to upgrade. :)

By further research of the modifications of the DOM while the loader shows up and hides again I found a solution without changing jquery or jq-mobile methods: I'm using the MutationObserver API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver

```
$j(document).bind('pageshow', function() {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if($j(mutation.target).hasClass('ui-loading')) {
                $j('.ui-loader').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                setTimeout(function() { $j('.ui-loader').css('visibility', 'visible'); }, 300);
            }
            else {
                $j('.ui-loader').css('visibility', 'visible');  
            }
        })
    });
    observer.observe(document.querySelector('html'), { attributes: true });     
});
```

This is not quite the solution I planned but it works fine for the moment...